# Can't run Numpy/scipy installed with conda - ImportError: undefined symbol Pyslice_Unpack

Tags: python, numpy, conda

I have created a new conda env and attempted to install numpy into it. After activating the env, I used `conda install numpy`. However, when I start `python` and attempt to `import numpy` I get the following import error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/tjim/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 112, in <module>
    import ctypes
  File "/home/tjim/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/ctypes/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array
ImportError: /home/tjim/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload/_ctypes.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: PySlice_Unpack
```

A similar error appears when I try to install scipy. I have also tried uninstalling them both and letting conda install numpy as a dependency of pandas but that didn't work either. What am I doing wrong? What info should I provide to help fix the problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I deleted my conda virtual env and started a fresh one, cloning my original anaconda install (which had a working numpy) using `conda create -n yourenvname python=3.6 anaconda` as a workaround.